# Node mysql pool.query await for result

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I'm using `node mysql` package.
I don't have much experience in JS and i'm trying to turn this function into an async function so i can wait for the result:

```
function execute_q (q) {
  var results = _this.pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results[0].solution)
  })
}
```

I've tried like this:

```
async function execute_async (q) {
  return await new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    _this.pool.query(
      q,
      function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(results)
        }
      })
  })
}
```

but when i run `var results = await execute_async(q)` i keep getting `await is only valid in async function`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: await is only allowed to be used inside an async function, show us where you call `execute_async(q)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `async` before the function in which you have placed the `execute_async(q)` function and check the result.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
async function execute_async (q) {

  try {
    var results = await _this.pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution');
    return results;
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work, this is what you want...

```
async function execute_q (q) {
    try {
        var results = await _this.pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution');
        console.log(results[0].solution);
        return results;
    }
    catch(err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line "var results = await _this.pool..." an error is thrown "await has no effect on this type of expression", and the code just hangs.